# React hooks: Set state 'ModalVisible' but state does not update immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I use setModalConfirmVisible(true) but the state modalConfirmVisible does not update immediately. So, Modal does not display.

How can I update this state immediately?

[image: See happened]
When I click Remove button. The console will show only false from

> console.log(modalConfirmVisible)

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        setFetchLoading(true)
        setTransactions(await fetchTransactions())
        setFetchLoading(false)
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }
    })()
  }, [modalConfirmVisible])

  async function handleRemoveTransaction(id) {
    setRemoveLoading(true)
    setModalConfirmVisible(true)
    console.log(modalConfirmVisible)
    await handleConfirmRemoveTransaction(true, id)
  }


  return (
    {modalConfirmVisible && (
      <ModalConfirm
        onConfirmRemove={handleConfirmRemoveTransaction}
        onCancel={() => setModalConfirmVisible(false)}
        visible={true} 
      />
    )}
  )


// ModalConfirm.js
const ModalConfirm = ({ onConfirmRemove, visible }) => {
  return (
    <Modal
      visible={visible}
      title="Do you want to delete these items?"
      icon={<ExclamationCircleOutlined />}
      content="When clicked the OK button, this dialog will be closed after 1 second"
      onOk={() => onConfirmRemove(true)}
      onCancel={() => onConfirmRemove(false)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Where `ModalConfirm` comes from? Please show the code from that component

Comment: Are you trying to, within `handleRemoveTransaction`, open the modal **AND** await the modal's `onConfirmRemove` callback to be called? This won't work as the state update is asynchronous and updated value isn't available for *this* render cycle. In other words, your awaiting the modal callback is blocking the modal from opening.

Comment: State updates are async. You can't see them directly after calling `setState`. You will only see them during the next render that a state update triggers. But this should not be a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to split out the logic of *opening* your modal from *handling* the confirmation. This allows the state update to set `modalConfirmVisible` and *then* on the next render cycle the `confirmModal` can open.

```
// from component in screen cap click remove, just open the modal
function openRemoveConfirmation() {
  setRemoveLoading(true)
  setModalConfirmVisible(true)
}

// handle confirmation separately
function handleRemoveTransaction(id) {
  handleConfirmRemoveTransaction(true, id)
}

return (
  {modalConfirmVisible && (
    <ModalConfirm
      onConfirmRemove={handleConfirmRemoveTransaction}
      onCancel={() => setModalConfirmVisible(false)}
      visible={true} 
    />
  )}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using react-hooks, so you change any `state` immediately.

The right way is to check the value of modalConfirmVisible in the next `cycle`. And because you `setState` and the state is changed, the function will execute again:

```
const [modalConfirmVisible, setModalConfirmVisible] = useState(false);

async function handleRemoveTransaction(id) {
  setRemoveLoading(true)
  setModalConfirmVisible(true)
  await handleConfirmRemoveTransaction(true, id)
}
console.log(modalConfirmVisible)
```